# Python API for PTZ ussing ONVIF: GetProfiles() -> Unknown fault occured

Tags: python, onvif, hikvision

I was trying to connect a ptz camera with API on python. But I faced a weird problem. The API can see the camera and return the hostname. But when I try to return the media profile (`GetProfiles()`) there is an error appears:

> zeep.exceptions.Fault: Unknown fault occured
> onvif.exceptions.ONVIFError: Unknown error: Unknown fault occured

Furthermore, the same code works well on different camera
('good' camera: DH-SD59232XA-HNR, Firmware: V2.810.0000017.1.R.P9.3217.UN.NR).
I'll be glad if anyone can help.

Camera: DS-2DE7A432IW-AEB
Firmware Version: V5.8.0 build 230519
WEB: V5.1.0_R0101 build 230213
ONVIF : 19.12

python 3.6
zeep==4.1.0
onvif-zeep==0.2.12

Code:

```
from onvif import ONVIFCamera

ptz_username = 'xxx'
ptz_password = 'yyy'
ptz_ip = '-.-.-.-'
ptz_port = 80

wsdl_folder = '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wsdl'

mycam = ONVIFCamera(ptz_ip, ptz_port, ptz_username, ptz_password, wsdl_folder)

resp = mycam.devicemgmt.GetHostname()
print(f'My camera`s hostname: {str(resp.Name)}')

media_service = mycam.create_media_service()

media_profile = media_service.GetProfiles()[0]
```

The error message:

```
My camera`s hostname: Hikvision
<onvif.client.ONVIFService object at 0x7f832d7320>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/onvif/client.py", line 23, in wrapped
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/onvif/client.py", line 153, in wrapped
return call(params, callback)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/onvif/client.py", line 140, in call
ret = func(**params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zeep/proxy.py", line 51, in call
kwargs,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zeep/wsdl/bindings/soap.py", line 135, in send
return self.process_reply(client, operation_obj, response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zeep/wsdl/bindings/soap.py", line 229, in process_reply
return self.process_error(doc, operation)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zeep/wsdl/bindings/soap.py", line 356, in process_error
detail=etree_to_string(doc),
zeep.exceptions.Fault: Unknown fault occured

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ptz_test.py", line 23, in
media_profile = media_service.GetProfiles()[0]
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/onvif/client.py", line 26, in wrapped
raise ONVIFError(err)
onvif.exceptions.ONVIFError: Unknown error: Unknown fault occured
```